# Rails: Devise with 2 models, logout logs out both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to implement a second devise resource of users to my Rails app. Log in works, but currently when logging out in one section, logs out both.

How can I  set up my application in order to be able to keep both separated?

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'users'
devise_for :admins, :path => 'admins'
```

application_controller.rb:

```
private

# Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if resource_or_scope == :user
    collection_path
  elsif resource_or_scope == :admin
    new_admin_session_path
  else
    root_path
  end
end

# Overwriting the sign_in redirect path method
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
stored_location_for(resource) ||
  if resource.is_a?(User)
    collection_opac_path
  elsif resource.is_a?(Admin)
    admin_root_path
  else
    super
  end
end
```

1.html

```
<%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_admin_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

2.html

```
<%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

LOG upon logging out user:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Feb 08 18:28:11 +0100 2019
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"somestring"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Admin Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `admins`.* FROM `admins` WHERE `admins`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `updated_at` = '2019-02-08 17:28:11', `remember_created_at` = NULL WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE `admins` SET `remember_created_at` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2019-02-08 17:28:11' WHERE `admins`.`id` = 1
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/collection
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Devise `sing_out` action affects all active scopes by default. To change this, set the following in **config/initializers/devise.rb**:

```
config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
```

Comment: thanks ... indeed there it is! Now sign out works. I wonder if there is a way to specify a different notice for each resources....